# Why is $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Groups}}(G,A)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ab}}(G/[G,G],A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology, group-homomorphism

This question is inspired by an exercise from the Weibel's book on Homological Algebra (beginning of chapter 6 on Group Cohomology).

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a $G$-module.
My question simply is:

> Why are the groups $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Groups}}(G,A)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ab}}(G/[G,G],A)$ isomorphic?

Any hint will be particularly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: $A$ should be an abelian group here. This is the universal property of the abelianization $G/[G, G]$. The point is that any morphism from $G$ to an abelian group must vanish on all commutators.

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan thank you, your comment plus the answer from Zev Chonoles helped me in finding a complete and clear solution. [however, according to my definition of $G$-module, $A$ is implicitly assumed to be abelian]. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any group homomorphism from a group $G$ to an abelian group $A$ must factor through the abelianization of $G$, that is, the quotient $G/[G,G]$.

In other words, if $G$ is a group and $A$ is an abelian group, then for any group homomorphism $f:G\to A$, there is a unique group homomorphism $\varphi$ from the abelian group $G/[G,G]$ to the abelian group $A$ such that $f=\varphi\circ q$, where $q:G\to G/[G,G]$ is the quotient map.

(In your situation, $A$ is an abelian group with extra structure, namely, a $G$-action. However this does not affect facts about group homomorphisms to $A$.)

The isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Groups}}(G,A)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ab}}(G/[G,G],A)$ sends $f$ to its corresponding $\varphi$.

([Relevant Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization))

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware about the nice universal property of the subgroup of the commutators.